# R: determining difference between max and min for certain subgroups within groups

Tags: r, dplyr, grouping, tidyverse, difference

Example data field below

```
Event        Ethnicity        Score
50 yd dash    Asian             7
50 yd dash    Afr. Am           8
50 yd dash    White             5
Hurdle        Asian             6
Hurdle        Afr. Am           8
Hurdle        White             9
```

I am trying to determine the difference between certain ethnicities within each event, hopefully using dplyr or something in tidyverse but will take any answer/help. For example, the difference between the Asian group and the White group in each event,

e.g., Asian (7) - White (5) = Difference (2),

resulting in output similar to below:

```
Event          Difference
50 yd dash         2
Hurdle            -3
```

Comment: Also, the titles says max and min, but that actually isnt entirely necessary as I will likely be selecting the groups rather than taking the max and min, but a max and min solution would be helpful as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using the following should get you there:

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>%
    spread(Ethnicity, Score) %>%
    mutate("Difference" = Asian - White) %>%
    select(-Asian, -White, -`Afr. Am`)
#       Event Difference
#1 50 yd dash          2
#2     Hurdle         -3
```

**DATA.**

```
df <-
structure(list(Event = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("50 yd dash", 
"Hurdle"), class = "factor"), Ethnicity = structure(c(2L, 1L, 
3L, 2L, 1L, 3L), .Label = c("Afr. Am", "Asian", "White"), class = "factor"), 
    Score = c(7L, 8L, 5L, 6L, 8L, 9L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-6L))
```

@AntoniosK already posted a `read.table` way of reading in the data posted by the OP but my approach was a bit different. Instead of removing the white spaces from the columns' values I have put them between single quotes. (It must be *single* quotes since the instruction puts the value of argument `text` between *double* quotes.)

```
df <- read.table(text = "
Event        Ethnicity        Score
'50 yd dash'    Asian             7
'50 yd dash'    'Afr. Am'           8
'50 yd dash'    White             5
Hurdle        Asian             6
Hurdle        'Afr. Am'           8
Hurdle        White             9
", header = TRUE)
```

Comment: Tested it and yes, it works. I will edit your answer with the data in `dput` format.

Comment: Out of curiosity: how did you get the data? I guess I am missing an important function here that I am still not aware of.

Comment: This is perfect! Thank you. Next time I will write code for the df

Comment: That is actually my bad. I wans't aware of the function to retrieve it. Happy coding!

Comment: See the edit, I believe it answers part of your issue on reading in data posted in tabular format.

Answer (score 3):

**Data**

```
df = read.table(text = "
Event        Ethnicity        Score
50yddash    Asian             7
50yddash    Afr.Am           8
50yddash    White             5
Hurdle        Asian             6
Hurdle        Afr.Am           8
Hurdle        White             9
", header=T, stringsAsFactors=F)
```

**First approach**, where you manually specify the ethnicities of interest:

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  group_by(Event) %>%
  summarise(Diff = Score[Ethnicity=="Asian"] - Score[Ethnicity=="White"])

# # A tibble: 2 x 2
#   Event     Diff
#   <chr>    <int>
# 1 50yddash     2
# 2 Hurdle      -3
```

You can use this piece of code as a function (with inputs the two ethnicities of interest).

**Second approach**, where you create all differences for all unique combinations of ethnicities and events:

```
library(tidyverse)

# create vectorised function that calculates the difference
# based on a given event and ethnicities
f = function(event, eth1, eth2) {
  df$Score[df$Event==event & df$Ethnicity==eth1] -
  df$Score[df$Event==event & df$Ethnicity==eth2] }
f = Vectorize(f)


data.frame(t(combn(unique(df$Ethnicity), 2)), stringsAsFactors = F) %>% # create combinations of ethnicities
  mutate(Event = list(unique(df$Event))) %>%                            # create combinations with events
  unnest() %>%
  mutate(Diff = f(Event, X1, X2))                                       # apply the function

#    X1     X2    Event Diff
# 1  Asian Afr.Am 50yddash   -1
# 2  Asian Afr.Am   Hurdle   -2
# 3  Asian  White 50yddash    2
# 4  Asian  White   Hurdle   -3
# 5 Afr.Am  White 50yddash    3
# 6 Afr.Am  White   Hurdle   -1
```

This process uses alphabetical order to create the unique differences. If you want all of them (i.e. Asian-White and White-Asian) you can use this

```
expand.grid(Event = unique(df$Event),
            X1 = unique(df$Ethnicity),
            X2 = unique(df$Ethnicity)) %>%
  filter(X1 != X2) %>%
  mutate(Diff = f(Event, X1, X2))                                     

#    Event     X1     X2 Diff
# 1  50yddash Afr.Am  Asian    1
# 2    Hurdle Afr.Am  Asian    2
# 3  50yddash  White  Asian   -2
# 4    Hurdle  White  Asian    3
# 5  50yddash  Asian Afr.Am   -1
# 6    Hurdle  Asian Afr.Am   -2
# 7  50yddash  White Afr.Am   -3
# 8    Hurdle  White Afr.Am    1
# 9  50yddash  Asian  White    2
# 10   Hurdle  Asian  White   -3
# 11 50yddash Afr.Am  White    3
# 12   Hurdle Afr.Am  White   -1
```

Comment: This is great! Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

```
df %>%
  mutate(rn = row_number()) %>%
  spread(Ethnicity, Score) %>%
  group_by(Event) %>%
  summarise(Difference = max(Asian, na.rm = T) - max(White, na.rm = T))

# # A tibble: 2 x 2
#   Event      Difference
#   <chr>           <dbl>
# 1 50 yd dash          2
# 2 Hurdle             -3
```

**Data:**

```
df <- 
structure(list(Event = c("50 yd dash", "50 yd dash", "50 yd dash", 
"Hurdle", "Hurdle", "Hurdle"), Ethnicity = c("Asian", "Afr. Am", 
"White", "Asian", "Afr. Am", "White"), Score = c(7, 8, 5, 6, 
8, 9)), row.names = c(NA, -6L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
))
```

Comment: Great! Thanks for coding the data into a proper df, too